# How to display two quantum circuits side by side using quantikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, quantikz

I have two quantum circuits that I'd like to display side by side using the `quantikz` package in LaTeX. Here's the code for the two circuits:

```
\begin{quantikz}
   & \ctrl{1} &  \\
   & \targ{}  &  
\end{quantikz}
$\equiv$
\begin{quantikz}
   & \qw & \ctrl{1} & \qw & \qw \\
   & \gate{H} & \gate{Z} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
\end{quantikz}
```

This is how it is displayed:

[image]

I've tried using the tabular environment as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494478/quantikz-side-by-side-and-titles), but the circuits are still not aligning properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` can be given to the `quantikz` environments. The `\\` at the end of the second `quantikz` environment is removed because it gives unwanted vertical space.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
 & \ctrl{1} & \\
 & \targ{} &
\end{quantikz}
$\equiv$
\begin{quantikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
 & \qw & \ctrl{1} & \qw & \qw \\
 & \gate{H} & \gate{Z} & \gate{H} & \qw
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```